# how to use non password protected (.p12) ssl certificate in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl

I have a .pem certificate which I have to use in my spring boot application.
Now, since java does not understand .pem format, I am converting it to .p12 format.

Since, we already have a .pem certificate which is not protected by any password, I am trying to avoid password for .p12 too.

I created two .p12 files, one is with password using below command :

```
openssl x509 -signkey sslcert.key  -in sslcert.csr   -req -days 365
-out sslcert.pem
```

And another without password using below command :

```
openssl pkcs12  -inkey sslcert.key  -in sslcert.pem  -export -passout
pass: -nokeys -out sslcert.p12
```

And I am able to get the results successfully using the one with password using the below properties in spring boot application :

```
server.port=8443  
server.ssl.enabled=true 
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12 
server.ssl.key-store=keys/sslcert.p12 
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
```

But when I am trying to use the one without password which is my preference, I am getting sslhandshake exception.

And also, I am not able to figure out how to pass this information to spring boot that ssl is not password protected.

SO far I tried many combinations like not passing password property or keeping it empty but it failed in all cases.

```
server.port=8443 
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=keys/sslcert.p12
```

I am getting below exception :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.flush(SslConnection.java:864)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.fillRequestBuffer(HttpConnection.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

SO, can any one throw some light on how to use non-password protected .p12 certificate in spring boot.

All googles articles seems to be telling about the password propected. SO is it a mandatory thing in java?

Comment: error message "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common" is certainly not related to the fact that the private key (associated to the certificate) is password protected or not. There is something different in your 2 certificates (maybe) that triggers different client behavior, and hence different server reply.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek if you look at the commands, I just changed to not to use any pwd.. apart from it , everything is same

Comment: Can you share the SSL logs? Add -Djavax.net.debug=ssl

Comment: @PatrickMevzek+ 'no cipher suites in common' causes clienthello to be rejected; server does not send any cert at all, so client can't possibly be affected by it. This does occur if the claimed 'keystore' actually contains only the cert and not the privatekey, as the second command shown `openssl pkcs12 -export -nokeys ...` would create. Onki: an SSL/TLS server _must_ have cert _and privatekey_ (_and_ chain certs if applicable, but `x509 -signkey` creates a self-signed cert that needs no chain certs). I'm not sure offhand if Java can use P12 without password at all.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085  it seems we cant use ssl certificates without passwords in java. So now I am trying to figure our a way to avoid hardcoded password. Exploring over option to pass non static password to spring boot application

Comment: If you didn't care that it was not encrypted, you shouldn't care about using a fixed static password for encryption like `secret` or `changeme`. There is zero difference in security between the two.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I was on similar viewpoint.. but as soon as we mention passwords, the question get raised about the bad design practice. so that is where we are going ahead with it.

Comment: Ok, well that depends on the politics in your company. It's not really a password if it's fixed, so you could have mentioned that since they were okay with an unencrypted key. Or you could say that the password is "not applicable" (and that's what your static password is) Or maybe the problem is (and actually, that should have been the problem) that you didn't highlight that they key is unencrypted; they shouldn't approve of that, and they should then tell you the company-approved method for securing private keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after all the research, it seems java key store needs a password.
So I had to ignore the .p12 which we had without password.
And using the pem certificate, we converted it to .p12 with password.
And I am doing this from spring code where I am passing random password to shell script which generates .p12 from .pem using that password.

And then I am passing the same password to ssl properties from the code.

one drawback is I have to regenerate .p12 from .pem every time application is restarted but this is how I prevent static password.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible wiithout setting password

Answer (score 0):

**By using a custom implementation of WebServerFactoryCustomizer and the BouncyCastle JCE provider, I was able to use a PKCS12 keystore without a password to serve SSL for a spring boot app.**

First I loaded the password-less PKCS12 (in my case, retrieved from Azure Key Vault) into a keystore with the BouncyCastle provider (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on):

```
    ByteArrayInputStream keyStoreStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pfxBytes);

    logger.info("Loading server cert keystore from Vault retrieved cert");
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");
    keyStore.load(keyStoreStream, "".toCharArray());
```

Then I put the keyStore into an implementation of org.springframework.boot.web.server.SslStoreProvider:

```
public class CustomSslStoreProvider implements SslStoreProvider {

    private KeyStore keyStore;
    private KeyStore trustStore;

    public CustomSslStoreProvider(KeyStore keyStore, KeyStore trustStore){
        this.keyStore = keyStore;
        this.trustStore = trustStore;
    }
```

And then I registered the CustomSslStoreProvider as a bean so it could be injected into my implementation of WebServerFactoryCustomizer so that it will be used by the embedded server:

```
@Component
public class CustomSSLServletContainer implements
        WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {


    @Autowired(required = false)
    private CustomSslStoreProvider sslStoreProvider;


    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        if(sslStoreProvider != null) {
            factory.setSslStoreProvider(sslStoreProvider);
        }
```

With this implementation, I still configured the key-alias in application.properties (unrelated I happened to require ssl client auth). However, you will not need to provide any of the server.ssl.key-store properties:

```
server.ssl.key-alias=panda-asfafa=asfaf
server.ssl.client-auth=need
```